# Result Calculation based on values/headers in other columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 4 columns and I need to do a calculation based on values there and there can be values in only one out of 4 columns:

[image]

I would need the number in the column name and multiply with first column as result. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

What I would ideally need

```
If df[10% percent] != 0 then :
   df[result] = 10  * df[Sum]
else if df[20% percent] != 0 then :
   df[result] = 20  * df[Sum]
.
.
.
.
```

in  a more efficient way!

Answer (score 0):

Isn't better to have a column called % and then in the cells the number? (10, 20,30...) this way you just need to do

```
df[result] = df[sum]*df[%]
```

Comment: Idellay will make things easier but Problem is its an input file from external system so i dont have a choice there.